# How to have angular controller respond to a variable's value change event

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am building an application where I have several controllers controlling various parts of the page. I would like for them to respond to specific model change events. For example when $scope.Variable has a change of value, I would like for controller A to run a certain method etc.

How do I respond to model change events with controllers in angular?

Comment: You are definitely looking for [`$watch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Rahil has it right: [$watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch) method